# Split functionality for consecutive occurence

Tags: apex, trigger, class, code

I have below code snippet for making immediate letter after space in capital. But this fails for consecutive two spaces and throws error. Can some one guide me here?

```
             List<String> CapsName= inputString.split(' ');
             String RetName='';
                for(Integer i=0;i<CapsName.size();i++)
                {
                    CapsName[i] = (CapsName[i].substring(0,1)).toUppercase() +(CapsName[i].substring(1,CapsName[i].length()));
                    if(i>0)
                    {
                        RetName=RetName+' '+CapsName[i];
                    }
                    else RetName=CapsName[i];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this much more simply by leveraging the `capitalize()` method on the String class

```
String res = '';
for (String token: inputString.split(' ')) 
  res += String.isEmpty(res) ? token.capitalize() : ' ' + token.capitalize();
```

The reason you were getting an exception is because the `split()` method was returning zero length strings when there were consecutive spaces - then you were then substring'ing and going past the length of the token (`CapsName[i]`)

The capitalize() method returns empty string if given an empty string.

Note you will need to decide what to do about `inputString = null` - should the code return null or empty string? I leave that as an exercise for you

Comment: Thanks ! Yes in my case it should return empty string so that validation rule can restrict for the required field.